# Testing Loss won't improve when doing Binary Classification using Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a dataset with 65 features and 2 labels and want to perform binary classification.

The problem is the testing loss wont improve nor will the testing accuracy.

**Training Loss vs Testing Loss**

[image: Training Loss vs Testing Loss]

**Training Accuracy vs Testing Accuracy**

[image: Training Acc vs Testing ACc]

**Code**

```
model = Sequential()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_dim=n_features))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['acc'])
```

The dataset is highly imbalanced (1:30)

How can I improve my model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Softmax and binary cross-entropy are not the right match, to use softmax correctly you should use the `categorical_crossentropy` loss. If you want to keep using a binary cross-entropy you should use a sigmoid activation at the output, with a single neuron (not two).

Comment: Will try this and mark this answer as correct one accordingly.

Comment: You are a genius! It would be great if you could share link to understand why softmax+categorical is not a good combination